# Inheriting from std::runtime_error

Tags: c++

I'm coding my own Exception class:

```
class Exception : public std::runtime_error{

}
```

And I would like overload `what()`. How can I do that?

Also, what do I have to keep in mind when inheriting from `std::runtime_error`?

Comment: What will you do if you want to have a logic error?

Comment: Do you mean *overload* or *override*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that as what is part of the runtime_error I believe it's virtual, so to overload it, you'd need to create a method with the exact same method signature.  So if you point your browser to: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/ then you'll see the definition of what()

So to overload it you'll need to do something like this in your header file:

```
class Exception : public runtime_error
{
    public:
        const char* what() const throw();
}
```

then you'd define it thus in your cpp file:

```
const char* Exception::what() const throw()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks! It very helped. But what does mean: const throw(); after  const char* what()

Comment: Happy to help, Please don't forget to click the tick to accept the answer.

Comment: @user3487199: const means that what() doesn't modify the object, throw() means that it doesn't throw.

Comment: I got CE
no matching function for call to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error()`

Comment: Note: In C++11 the throw() is replaced by noexcept

Comment: I got CE no matching function for call to std::runtime_error::runtime_error() –  user3487199 2 mins ago   edit

Comment: It doesn't inherit from runtime_error though, runtime_error itself inherits it from the exception class in c++.

Comment: It doesn't inherit from runtime_error though, runtime_error itself inherits it from the exception class in c++. What is difference?

Comment: Do you want to e-mail me what you've done so far and I'll take a look?  My address is in my profile.  So I can see the code in context etc.